# How to display Mapbox tile layer

Tags: leaflet

I'm attempting to use this simple example from LeafletJS but am unable to get the layer to display using my Mapbox public key.  The map displays a grey background with my sample marker and pop up.

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([39.5, -105.5], 7);

L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
maxZoom: 18,
id: 'test.project',
accessToken: 'copied.and.pasted.my.mapbox.key.here'
}).addTo(mymap);

L.marker([39.5, -105.5]).addTo(map)
.bindPopup('This is my first marker!')
.openPopup();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `.addTo(mymap);` on the tilelayer, but your map object is `map`. Use this: `.addTo(map);`

You might also have to change the URL a bit. Following the [documentation here](https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#retrieve-raster-tiles-from-styles) I created a map based on a **style**:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([39.5, -105.5], 7);

L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{username}/{id}/tiles/{tileSize}/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
  attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
  maxZoom: 18,
  username: 'mapbox username',
  id: 'mapbox style id',
  accessToken: 'mapbox access token',
  tileSize: 512, 
  zoomOffset: -1
}).addTo(map);

L.marker([39.5, -105.5]).addTo(map)
  .bindPopup('This is my first marker!')
  .openPopup();
```

If you want to retrieve tiles for a certain **tileset** use this ([documentation](https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#retrieve-tiles)):

```
L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/v4/{tilesetId}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={accessToken}', {
  attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
  maxZoom: 18,
  accessToken: 'mapbox access token',
  tilesetId: 'mapbox tileset id'
}).addTo(map);
```

`tilesetId` has the form of `username.id`, it's not your project's name, you can find it in the editor/Studio.

Comment: I've fixed the mismatch and the tile layer is still not displaying.  When I access the URL alone, I get an object indicating {"message":"Not Found"}.  I'm reading some threads indicating that Leaflet.js is broken and the new key process doesn't integrate with Mapbox anymore.